# Freemarker: Subtracting a date from Today's date

Tags: freemarker

I am wondering what the best way to subtract a date from today's date is in Freemarker?

I have a user's sign up date in this format: 2015-06-15 05:12:35.890 and what I am looking to do is get the number of years between when they signed up and now. (whole years, no need for 1 year 6 months / 1.5 yrs for example)

I have tried:

```
<#assign year=SIGN_UP_DATE?date(“yyyy”)>

<#assign today=now?date(“yyyy”)>

${dayadd(year, today)}
```

But this produces an error that the second parameter must be a number.

Can anyone enlighten me on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A formatted date is a string, not a number (even if they happen to look like a number to a human), so you have to convert them further to a number, like `<#assign year=SIGN_UP_DATE?date(“yyyy”)?number>`. Same with the other one. Now they can be subtracted with the `-` operator. (I'm not sure what's up with `dayadd`; to get the difference in years, you just need a subtraction.)